# Excel/Calc/Whatever: Flip my axes - ie reflect my table across the diagonal

Tags: microsoft-excel, openoffice-calc, libreoffice-calc

Lets say I have a table and I want it flipped across the diagonal.  So instead of X by Y its Y by X...

Before:

```
         A       B      C
RED      1       2      3
BLUE     4       5      6
```

Becomes:

```
         RED     BLUE
A        1       4
B        2       5
C        3       6
```

Is there an easy, built-in way to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Microsoft Excel 2007:

1. Copy (*not* cut) the data to be "flipped".
2. Click in the upper left corner of a *non-overlapping* region where you want the data to be flipped into.  (You might want to do this in a new worksheet.)
3. Click on the arrow (triangle) below the Paste icon.
4. Click on **Transpose**.  
   [image: Screen shot of Microsoft Excel 2007 Paste menu.]
   It’s the same in Excel 2013,
       [image: Screen shot of Microsoft Excel 2013 Paste menu]
   but this is what the menu looks like.

Answer (score 8):

Copy > Paste Special > Check/Select "Transpose"

Comment: I know this works in excel. Does it work in the others as well?

Comment: I don't have either set up, so I'm not sure. I know this feature is NOT available in Google Docs though.

Comment: This is correct for LibreOffice Calc.